# How to avoid pandas class overriding?

Tags: python, pandas, inheritance

I have built a dataset containing information of time lapses. In order to make readings simpler both on the terminal and the Spyder IDE, I have created a custom class which inherits from `datetime.timedelta` and its only changes were in representation methods (`__repr__` and `__str__`):

```
from datetime import timedelta

class tdn(timedelta):
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.total_seconds() < 0:
            abst = 'D'
        elif self.total_seconds() > 0:
            abst = 'C'
        else:
            return '{}(0)'.format(self.__class__.__qualname__)
        hh, s1 = divmod(abs(self.total_seconds()), 3600)
        mm = s1 // 60

        return '{}({}, hours={:n}, minutes={:n})'\
            .format(self.__class__.__qualname__, abst, hh, mm)
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.total_seconds() < 0:
            abst = '-'
        else:
            abst = ''
        hh, s1 = divmod(abs(self.total_seconds()), 3600)
        mm = s1 // 60

        return '{}{:02n}:{:02n}'.format(abst, hh, mm)
```

However, when explicitly applied in a Pandas DataFrame, it converts the supposed new class to pandas's [own timedelta class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
In [1]: a = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date':
        {0: datetime.date(2020, 9, 30),
         1: datetime.date(2020, 10, 1),
         2: datetime.date(2020, 10, 2),
         3: datetime.date(2020, 10, 5)},
     'lapse':
        {0: tdn(minutes=31),
         1: tdn(minutes=51),
         2: tdn(minutes=-38),
         3: tdn(minutes=41)}})
Out[1]:
         date             lapse
0  2020-09-30          00:31:00
1  2020-10-01          00:51:00
2  2020-10-02 -1 days +23:22:00
3  2020-10-05          00:41:00
```

When we inspect the `lapse` series, you can see that conversion has taken place:

```
In [2]: a['lapse'].dtype
Out[2]: dtype('<m8[ns]')

In [3]: type(a.loc[0, 'lapse'])
Out[3]: pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta
```

**Is there any way to avoid pandas overriding my custom class?** My sole goal: to have the `__str__` method come out as expected when calling the DataFrame on the terminal without having to explicitly convert to string using `strftime` or similar.

Obs: using `a['lapse'].astype(tdn)` will throw a `TypeError: dtype '<class '__main__.tdn'>' not understood`

Comment: `pandas` isn't overriding your custom class. Pandas will use more primitive dtypes for time, this is a *good thing*, this makes it fast and efficient. You can try using `dtype=object` explicitly, but this will affect performance. whether that is a big deal is up to you

Comment: The idea is that pandas is mainly built to be a data manipulation tool, not visualization. By "forcing" your `type` (and hence the `object` dtype), you lose all the data manipulation power of pandas and end up with a very expensive and heavy `pretty print` library

Comment: @rafaelc, it's not a large dataset, so I'm not worried about performance in this case.